# Weird behaviour : Activity not getting started again when first started with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

My scenario is,

When application starts then after user logs in I am starting an activity in the following manner,

```
Intent rangeFinderScreen = new Intent(YourLocationScreen.this, RangeFinderScreen.class);
rangeFinderScreen.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(rangeFinderScreen);
```

I am using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` so that all previous activity stack gets cleared and it starts as a new task.

Then I have bottom bar to navigate between activities, so I have made a common listener (Activity) and implemented that in all the activities. It looks like the following,

```
public class CommonListenerForBottomButtons extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    Context context;
    String buttonName;

    public CommonListenerForBottomButtons(Context context, String buttonName){
        this.context = context;
        this.buttonName = buttonName;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(buttonName){
            case "play":
                Intent rangefinder = new Intent(context, RangeFinderScreen.class);
                rangefinder.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(rangefinder);
                break;

                // and so on more cases

        }
    }
}
```

**Concern**

If while starting the activity for first time I do the following,

```
Intent rangeFinderScreen = new Intent(YourLocationScreen.this, RangeFinderScreen.class);
startActivity(rangeFinderScreen);
```

**Then all works**.

But if I do it the following way (as I am doing now), i.e. by using `rangeFinderScreen.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);`

Then activity **doesn't get started** again.

However if I start activity from any other activity rather than the Common Listener Activity like,

```
Intent rangefinder = new Intent(MyGolflerScreen.this, RangeFinderScreen.class);
startActivity(rangefinder);
```

**Then it starts**.

**EDIT**

Below is how I am initializing Common Listener in all activities:

```
homeLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new CommonListenerForBottomButtons(getApplicationContext(), "home"));
playLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new CommonListenerForBottomButtons(getApplicationContext(), "play"));
weatherLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new CommonListenerForBottomButtons(getApplicationContext(), "weather"));
messageLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new CommonListenerForBottomButtons(getApplicationContext(), "message"));
myGolflerLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new CommonListenerForBottomButtons(getApplicationContext(), "mygolfer"));
```

All other activities start except for the one which is initially started with the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

**Manifest file entry**

```
<activity
    android:name=".RangeFinderScreen"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_range_finder_screen"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```

Comment: you mean on backpress of rangefinderscreen class\

Comment: @koutuk No, on clicking on the Bottom Nav Bar button which has common listener.

Comment: are you getting valid context while using navigation Tab second time

Comment: @koutuk Yes. It is correct

Comment: if possibleplease post code where you are initalzing the common listner .... same thing happns wid fragments when we bind 2-3 fragments....and make some activity navigations ...

Comment: @koutuk code added. Context is right because all other activities start, only this activity doesn't start.

Comment: @DavidWasser Complete `manifest` file is too big for this question. I have declared the Listener in Manifest also. What else can I check?

Comment: please correct if i am wrong ..for example.. you press play > home > again play  now this time play activity is not calling right...

Comment: Post the manifest entry for the Activity that isn't being correctly restarted.

Comment: @koutuk Yes. Initially I am starting Play Activity ( without clicking on any button ) its starts. Then I go to Home, It starts then again I press Play, it doesn't start.

Comment: getApplicationContext() containig which class reference ??? while init. common listner

Comment: @koutuk I have made it a common listener for multiple activities and in each activity I am using `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: m trying wid code will let u know asap....

Answer (score 0):

Do not set the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` when you launch an Activity from another Activity within your application. This isn't necessary and is probably causing your problem.

Also, if you are starting a new `Activity` every time the user clicks on a button you will find that you are creating new instances of these activities every time, and will end up with a big stack of them after awhile. This probably isn't the desired behaviour either. To switch between activities that may already be in the task stack you can set the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`.

Comment: I myself said this problem is being caused by `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and due to some requirement I must clear all the previous activity task, so I need to use them both `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`

Comment: If you need to set `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` then you also need to set `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. However, in the `switch` statement in your listener you are setting only `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and this is probably causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is to manage all stacks i prefer to use all "singleTop" Activities and starting them with flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` 
It will manage all you want to do.

you can add `launchMode` in Manifest inside activity tag that is equal to `"singleTop"` .

Hope it works ...